# How to stop firing the ajax event everytime i click on p:selectOneMneu arrow icon?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:selectOneMenu tag inside a datatable + an onRowSelect event on the p:datatable. My problem is the rowSelect event gets fired everytime i click the down arrow inside the icon @ the right of the select menu. Which of course does some rerendering so the menu opens for a blink of an eye then closes again on rerendering. This issue does not happen when i click on the body of the select menu, which of course is not acceptable. Any Ideas? I can replace with h:selectOneMenu which behaves normally and doesn't fire the selection. However i need the filtering attributes of the p:selectOneMenu.

Here's the code sample :

```
<p:dataTable  id="inParametersDataTable" selection="#{wFDesignBean.selectedParameter}"
                                              selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{p.parameterDefinitionModel.parameterId}"
                                              value="#{wFDesignBean.selectedActivityModel.inParameterModels}"
                                              style="height: 100%; " var="p" >
                                    <p:ajax global="false" event="rowSelect" listener="#{wFDesignBean.loadSelectedParameter}"
                                            update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView" />
                                    <p:ajax global="false" event="rowUnselect" listener="#{wFDesignBean.clearAllParameterChoices()}" update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView"/>

                                    <f:facet id="facetId" name="header" >
                                        <h:commandButton  id="addNewParam" label="Add New Input Parameter" image="/styling/images/add.png" style="height:15px;" >
                                            <p:ajax global="false" event="click" listener="#{wFDesignBean.addInParameterToSelectedActivity}" update="inParametersDataTable"/>
                                        </h:commandButton> &nbsp;
                                        <h:commandButton label="Reload current parameters list" image="/styling/images/refresh.png" style="height:15px;" >
                                            <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{wFDesignBean.reloadParameters()}" update="inParametersDataTable"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;
                                        <h:commandButton label="Create a new parameter" image="/styling/images/createNew.png" style="height:15px;" >
                                            <p:ajax global="false" event="click"  listener="#{navigationBean.showParametersDialog}" update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <h:commandButton   id="delete" image="/styling/images/Delete-icon.png" style="height:15px;">
                                            <p:ajax global="false" event="click"  listener="#{wFDesignBean.removeInParam(p)}" update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Parameter Name">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="paramValues"  value="#{p.parameterDefinitionModel.parameterId}" >
                                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{wFDesignBean.defaultDropDownValue}" itemLabel="--Select Parameter--"/>
                                            <f:selectItems value ="#{wFDesignBean.paramSourceDef}" var="pra" itemLabel="#{pra.parameter_Name}" itemValue="#{pra.parameter_ID}"/>
                                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{wFDesignBean.loadSelectedParameterDefinitionData(p.parameterDefinitionModel.parameterId)}" update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Data Source">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="ddsValues" value="#{p.parameterSourceId}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="0"/>
                                            <f:selectItems value ="#{wFDesignBean.dataSourceValues}" var="ds" itemLabel="#{ds.lookupValue}" itemValue="#{ds.lookupId}"/>
                                            <p:ajax global="false" event="change" listener="#{wFDesignBean.handleParameterChoices(p)}" update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView"/>
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Is Optional">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="isOptional" value="#{p.isOptional}">
                                            <f:selectItems value ="#{wFDesignBean.isOptionalLookUp}" var="optional" itemLabel="#{optional.lookupValue}" itemValue="#{optional.lookupId}"/>
                                            <p:ajax global="false" event="change" update=":cont:tabView:bottomTabView"/>
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Already built">
                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{p.isAlreadyBuiltBool}">
                                            <p:ajax global="false" listener="#{wFDesignBean.setAlreadyBuilt()}"/>
                                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Where you have used `onRowSelect event` ?

Comment: You can try [radio/checkbox selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf;jsessionid=139db70b1p9ts19edyhbh6zfmv) it'll fire the event only when the selector is clicked.

Comment: not applicable, let me clarify , in each row i have a selectOneMenu, the problems happens when i try to open this select one menu through clicking it's icon (downward triangle/arrow), thanks anyways :D.

Comment: + @ Diganta/ all , sorry i pasted the wrong piece of code this is my case exactly.